# Pause rotating circles on a circular path with active classes

Tags: jquery, css

Currently have the following which is based over SO code which is image circles rotating on a circular path using css and jquery.
https://jsfiddle.net/hmarks/8L1rodg6/21/

```
var pos = $('#center').position(),
    radiusSat = $('#sat1').width() * 0.5,
    radius = $('#center').width() * 0.5,
    cx = pos.left + radius,
    cy = pos.top + radius,
    x, y, angle = 0, angles = [],
    spc = 360 / 8,
    deg2rad = Math.PI / 180,
    i = 0;

for(;i < 8; i++) {
    angles.push(angle);
    angle += spc;
}

/// space out radius
radius += (radiusSat - 25);

loop();

function loop() {

    for(var i = 0; i < angles.length; i++) {

        angle = angles[i];

        x = cx + radius * Math.cos(angle * deg2rad);
        y = cy + radius * Math.sin(angle * deg2rad);

        $('#sat' + i).css({left:x - radiusSat, top:y - radiusSat});

        angles[i] = angles[i] + 1;
        if (angles[i] > 360) angles[i] = 0;
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
```

It currently spins endlessly but hoping to accomplish the following:

[image]

So ultimately need it to pause momentarily after rotating 45 degrees and the top left and bottom right would be assigned an class of active and the word in the center would change each time the circles rotate 45 degrees.

Can utilize the latest version of jQuery if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I made some changes to the initial problem you have. I am not sure when you want to add the class "active". But from the code I came to a conclusion that any element at angle 45 and 225 should have the class active. So Why not just use

div[data-angle="225"] and div [data-angle="45"] for selecting them ?.

Regarding pausing them, its straight forward all you need to do is don't call the requestAnimationFrame when you reach the angle

```
function loop() {
    //consider this as steps of animation
    if(angles[0] ==45) {
         pause(5500, 1); 
    } else if(angles[0] ==90) {
         pause(5500, 2); 
    }else if(angles[0] ==135) {
      pause(5500, 3); 
    }else if(angles[0] ==180) {
      pause(5500, 0);
    }else if(angles[0] ==225) {
      pause(5500, 1); 
    }else if(angles[0] ==270) {
      pause(5500, 2);
    }else if(angles[0] ==315) {
      pause(5500, 3);
    }else if(angles[0] ==0) {
      pause(5500, 0);
    }else {
            requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    }   
            for(var i = 0; i < angles.length; i++) {
        var angle = angles[i];        
        x = cx + radius * Math.cos(angle * deg2rad);
        y = cy + radius * Math.sin(angle * deg2rad);
        $('#sat' + i).css({left:x - radiusSat, top:y - radiusSat});
        $('#sat' + i).attr('data-angle', angle);
        angles[i] = angles[i] + 1;
        if(angles[i] == 360) angles[i] =0;       
    }

}

function pause(time, id){   
    $(".text").hide();
  $(".text:eq("+id+")").show();  
    setTimeout(function(){
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
  }, time); 
}
```

I have attached a sample fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/Lmcn7brm/

Comment: You are a god. After spending far too much time working through various examples on SO, this is very elegant. Thanks so much!